# Django rest framework to_representation must be implemented

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

This issue has similar headings to other threads on this forum, but I'm sure this is not a duplicate because one because I didn't overwrite my pagination details or anything (which turned out to be the cause in other questions).

Anyways, Django raised `to_representation()` must be implemented. I'm completely stuck as there is no relevant documentation regarding this (please comment if you have some) and my case didn't fit in with other people's.

**For those of you that think I didn't include everything in the error message, the error message is just this short and ambiguous.** View this on [github issues](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7422)

[image]

Code:

settings

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = ['rest_framework',]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

view

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Todo
from .serializers import TodoSerializer

class TodoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
```

serializers

```py
from .models import Todo
from rest_framework import serializers

class TodoSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'desc', 'level', 'created']
```

urls

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'todos', views.TodoViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Many thanks in advance. Note: in case you're wondering is this all, this IS all as I jus started to learn drf a few moments ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use `class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):` not BaseSerializer

Comment: Raised `Class TodoSerializer missing "Meta" attribute`. What shall I include in this?

Comment: sorry man i don't understand how "Meta" attribute missing, if you write such as ```class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'desc', 'level', 'created']```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ModelSerializer to resolve this issue.